# How to get App launch source in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Is there any method to get App launch source(from home icon or other like notification bar etc.) in RN?

Or native way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can think of there should be 3 different launch source for an app.

1. Home Icon
2. Notification
3. App Link

I don't think there is a direct way of knowing what is the source of launch but what you can do is to eliminate options one by one and end up the one which is used.

For example;

First you can check for if the app is opened with an app link. You can use [Linking API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) for this.

> [`getInitialURL()`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#getinitialurl)
>
> If the app launch was triggered by an app link, it will give the link
>   url, otherwise it will give `null`

If the app did not launched with a link then you can check for notification data. There is lots of different libraries and techniques for using notifications with react-native and most of them has an event listener for notification data. You can check for any notification data and see if you are going to get any. React-native has [`PushNotificationIOS`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html) for native IOS notifications. Just to give you an idea you can use [`getDeliveredNotifications()`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#getdeliverednotifications).

> `getDeliveredNotifications()`
>
> ```
> PushNotificationIOS.getDeliveredNotifications(callback);
> ```
>
> Provides you with a list of the app’s notifications that are still
>   displayed in Notification Center

If both of these tries return with no information or data then app must be launched from home icon.

Comment: That should be `PushNotificationIOS.getinitialnotification()` https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#getinitialnotification